# How to Reference Javascript for Office functions in Excel VBA?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, exceljs

I am re-writing several commonly used VBA Macros in JavaScript API for Office. (I'm doing this because my supervisor has asked me to, and they are used hundreds of time across many different Macro-Enabled Excel Workbooks.) These functions include functions that create tables, duplicate template sheets, and importing data from other sources. (I don't want to have to create an Excel Javascript Add-On with everything on it because it would not include templates and for how long it would take.)

When I try to import a JavaScript or HTML file directly into Visual Basic for Application, it (of course) runs into an error of not being able to compile the code. So I can't import it like a normal Basic file. I can import a JavaScript Add-On into Excel, but I don't know how to reference it in VBA.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
//Javascript
export async function getWsInExcel() {
try {
await Excel.run(async context => {
return context.worksheet;

await context.sync();
});
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
```

```vb
'VBA
Sub getWorksheetFromJS()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = JSAddOn.getWsInExcel
ws.Cells(1,1).Value = Hello World
End Sub
```

This should enter "Hello World" into the current sheet in cell A1.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good example. Can you share a more detailed example of what you're trying to do? Note that VBA is not based on the .Net framework; VBA is different from VB.NET.

Comment: VBA predates .NET by a decade... What's the point of using JavaScript to "get the current workseet" in VBA, when `ActiveSheet` is readily available, right there, and gives you exactly that?

Comment: That said, your `JSAddOn` API would have documentation about how to use it, no?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I have a couple dozen functions that I re-use in macros quite frequently, such as one that create a sheet based on a template, one that imports data from another source, or one that makes a table in a sheet that used my several different Macros across many different workbooks for different, specific purposes. But I don't want every workbook to have the same, very specific functions available to them; only the general ones. So I'm trying to import general functions for my specific-purpose macros. Does that clarify?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better reflect the actual problem, perhaps with a better, more concrete example, as @BigBen suggested. VBA and JavaScript in the same post is definitely going to raise questions, if not eyebrows: best be very clear and specific about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and how it failed. General and vague "how do I..." questions tend to end up closed and unanswered.

Comment: Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Why not switch to googlesheets?

Comment: @QHarr, my company doesn't use Google Sheets, and Google Sheets would likely be too slow to process the amount of information we need to process.